# Remove ads from webpage code

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, adblock, mechanicalsoup

I have list of adblock rules ([example](https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/ruadlist+easylist.txt))
How can I apply them to webpage? I download webpage code with MechanicalSoup (based on BeautifulSoup). I would like to save it in bs format, but etree is fine too.
I tried to use [following code](https://github.com/buriy/python-readability/issues/43#issuecomment-321174825), but it has problems with some pages:
`ValueError: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported. Please use bytes input or XML fragments without declaration.`

Comment: Please update your question with the URL(s) that failed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Virtually the same code as in Nikita's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49728763/4796844), but wanted to share it with all the imports, without `mechanicalsoup` dependency for people who'd like to try it out.

```
from lxml.etree import tostring
import lxml.html
import requests

# take AdRemover code from here:
# https://github.com/buriy/python-readability/issues/43#issuecomment-321174825
from adremover import AdRemover

url = 'https://google.com'  # replace it with a url you want to apply the rules to  
rule_urls = ['https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/ruadlist+easylist.txt',
             'https://filters.adtidy.org/extension/chromium/filters/1.txt']

rule_files = [url.rpartition('/')[-1] for url in rule_urls]


# download files containing rules
for rule_url, rule_file in zip(rule_urls, rule_files):
    r = requests.get(rule_url)
    with open(rule_file, 'w') as f:
        print(r.text, file=f)


remover = AdRemover(*rule_files)

html = requests.get(url).text
document = lxml.html.document_fromstring(html)
remover.remove_ads(document)
clean_html = tostring(document).decode("utf-8")
```

Comment: hey that's not contain adremover  in AdRemover and i try your code and get following error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'adremover'

Answer (score 1):

So I came up with this solution:

```
ADBLOCK_RULES = ['https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/ruadlist+easylist.txt',  
                 'https://filters.adtidy.org/extension/chromium/filters/1.txt']

for rule in ADBLOCK_RULES:
    r = requests.get(rule)
    with open(rule.rsplit('/', 1)[-1], 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)

browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser(
    soup_config={'features': 'lxml'},
    raise_on_404=True
)
response = browser.open(url)
webpage = browser.get_current_page()
html_code = re.sub(r'\n+', '\n', str(webpage))
remover = AdRemover(*[rule.rsplit('/', 1)[-1] for rule in ADBLOCK_RULES])
tree = lxml.html.document_fromstring(html_code)
adblocked = remover.remove_ads(tree)
webpage = BeautifulSoup(ElementTree.tostring(adblocked).decode(), 'lxml')
```

You need to use [following code](https://github.com/buriy/python-readability/issues/43#issuecomment-321174825), but with updated remove_ads() by `return tree`